# Control-C not stopping thread/spinning cursor

Tags: python, multithreading

I have code that copies files. When it is doing so a cursor spins. This all works fine. However if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the copy I expect the `KeyboardInterrupt` to set the event and the cursor to stop spinning. The copy stops however the cursor spins forever, why is this?

I tried putting a print into the Interrupt and that did not get displayed, so it seems it is not being called?

```
def spinning_cursor(event):
      for j in itertools.cycle('/-\|'):
          if not event.is_set():
              sys.stdout.write(j)
              sys.stdout.flush()
              time.sleep(0.1)
              sys.stdout.write('\b')
          else:
              return


def copy_file(sfile, dfile, sync):
    processing_flag = Event()
    Thread(target = spinning_cursor, kwargs = {'event': processing_flag}).start()
    if os.path.exists(sfile):
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(sfile, dfile)
            processing_flag.set()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            processing_flag.set()
            pass
        ...
```

Comment: How long does it take for the code inside de try to run?

Comment: @TristanT Depends on file size, from a few seconds to an hour plus.

Comment: maybe it is allready finished when you tap ctrl c

Comment: @TristanT I have tried it with a bigger file now, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really an answer, because I cannot explain what really happens, but I could partially reproduce. It looks like `copy_file` *swallows* the KeyboardInterrupt and raises another exception. If that happens, as the `processing_flag.set()` is only in the normal and `except KeyboardInterrupt` branches, control never passes there. As a consequence, the Event is never set and the child thread keeps on spinning (that's what I did to reproduce the behaviour...)

#### Workarounds.

I could find 2 possible workarounds

- use `except` without any filtering:

  ```
  try:
      shutil.copyfile(sfile, dfile)
      processing_flag.set()
  except:
      processing_flag.set()
      pass
  ```

  that should be enough to catch any possible exception raised by `copyfile`
- use a `finally` block. I personally prefere that way, because it is really what `finally` is aimed to: execute that branch whatever could happen. In that case, you could even remove the `except` block and have just a `try:... finally:...`:

  ```
  try:
      shutil.copyfile(sfile, dfile)
  finally:
      processing_flag.set()
  ```

Comment: Thanks, both of those work. I was so caught up in the middle of it I didn't consider that the exception could be different.